# Big-Theta Notation Analysis

Tags: runtime, big-o

[image]
For the first question, I was able to come up with counter-example. However, I can't think of proper counter-example for the second question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Hint: Since `f`(n) is `Omega(g(n))`, suppose `f(n) = k*g(n)` for some constant `k`. What is `log(f(n))` in terms of `log(g(n))`?

Comment: Complexity analysis is indeed important to programming, so upvoted this question.

Comment: @DavidGuan thank you for the support and upvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition of `\Theta`, there are two constants `c1` and `c2` such that for each `n` we have `c1 * g(n) < f(n) < c2 * g(n)`. As log is an increasing function, we can apply log on each sides of the inequality: `log(c1) + log(g(n)) < log(f(n)) < log(c2)  + log(g(n))`. Hence, base on the definition of `\Theta(n)`, we have `log(f(n)) = \Theta(log(g(n))`, and you can't find any countersxample for this case.